# Gridview Asp NET desaparece o Sort depois de Click para realizar Update

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Tenho a minha `Gridview` desenvolvida manualmente, o problema e que quando clico para realizar o `update` a minha `gridview` deixa de se encontrar ordenada e volta ao seu estado normal. Pretendia que isso não acontecesse.

Aqui demonstro como se encontra definida:

```
 protected void CarregaGV(DateTime data,int tipo,string tipoSande)
    {
        DataTable dt = null;

        dt = TrataDados.GetDetailsProductLayout(data, tipo,tipoSande);

        Session["TaskTable"] = dt;
        GridViewLayoutProduto.DataSource = dt;
        GridViewLayoutProduto.DataBind();
    }

    private string GetSortDirection(string column)
    {

        // By default, set the sort direction to ascending.
        string sortDirection = "ASC";

        // Retrieve the last column that was sorted.
        string sortExpression = ViewState["SortExpression"] as string;

        if (sortExpression != null)
        {
            // Check if the same column is being sorted.
            // Otherwise, the default value can be returned.
            if (sortExpression == column)
            {
                string lastDirection = ViewState["SortDirection"] as string;
                if ((lastDirection != null) && (lastDirection == "ASC"))
                {
                    sortDirection = "DESC";
                }
            }
        }

        // Save new values in ViewState.
        ViewState["SortDirection"] = sortDirection;
        ViewState["SortExpression"] = column;

        return sortDirection;
    }

    protected void GridViewLayoutProduto_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        //Retrieve the table from the session object.
        DataTable dt = Session["TaskTable"] as DataTable;

        if (dt != null)
        {
            //Sort the data.

            dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);
            sort = e.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);
            //Session["TaskTable"] = ((DataView)GridViewLayoutProduto.DataSource).ToTable();
            GridViewLayoutProduto.DataSource = Session["TaskTable"];
            GridViewLayoutProduto.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void GridViewLayoutProduto_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewLayoutProduto.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        //CheckBox alt = GridViewLayoutProduto.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox;
        //alt.Enabled = false;
        BindData();
    }

    protected void GridViewLayoutProduto_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewLayoutProduto.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GridViewLayoutProduto.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridViewLayoutProduto_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewLayoutProduto.EditIndex = -1;
        BindData();
    }

    private void BindData()
    {

            GridViewLayoutProduto.DataSource = Session["TaskTable"];
            GridViewLayoutProduto.DataBind();


    }
```

Penso que o problema se encontra no `Session`["TaskTable"] porque guardo sempre o estado inical da Grid penso eu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme os seu código, após o sort, o datatable da sessão fica desatualizado. Qualquer evento que carregue o novamente volta para o estado inicial.

De qualquer forma, toda vez que o CarregaDV for chamado, vai colocar o Grid no estado inicial.

No evento GridViewLayoutProduto_Sorting voce esta colocando o datatable da secao ao inves do datatable ordenado.

```
 if (dt != null)
    {
        //Sort the data.

        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        dv.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);
        DataTable sortedDT = dv.ToTable();
        Session["TaskTable"] = sortedDT;
        GridViewLayoutProduto.DataSource = sortedDT;
        GridViewLayoutProduto.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: dt.ToTable não existe pelo menos dá me erro.

Comment: Corrigi. Editei o codigo.